# Login Page and writing data to CSV file

Tags: java, csv, login-page

I'm coding a simple application with a login page, I created a page for creating a new user, it should ask for the Username once and the Password twice, the injected data should be stored in an empty CSV file that already exists...
I searched the internet and this is what I came up with.

```
public void setCreateButton() throws Exception {

    String newUsername = usernameTextField.getText();
    String newUserPassword = passwordField.getText();
    String confirmedPassword = confirmPasswordField.getText();

    try {
        if (newUserPassword.equals(confirmedPassword)) {
            File file = new File("D:\\Users\\login.csv");
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.append(newUsername);
            stringBuilder.append(',');
            stringBuilder.append(newUserPassword);
            stringBuilder.append('\n');
            printWriter.write(stringBuilder.toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Password are not matched");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

when I run the code it doesn't generate any error but also it makes no changes to the CSV file, of course, I'm doing something wrong but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Can you show how you capture the user name and both password entries from the text entry fields on your GUI? If somehow these items are not properly captured nothing will be written to the csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to flush the writer:

```java
printWriter.flush();
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't think it would be that simple, thank you bro.

Comment: Even better would be to _close_ the writer (since you're not using it again and you don't want to leak resources). Preferably close it using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: I also guess I'm missing a line here because every time I create a new user it overwrites the old one, any quick tip ??